# How can a dynamically built argument can proper handle whitespace using /bin/sh?

Tags: variables, sh, whitespace, quoting

I am bound to using `/bin/sh`. :(

In the following example, I need to pass an optional dynamically built argument to the command `openssl`:

```
#!/bin/sh

function foo() {
  local dynamic_arg="-passout pass:$1"
  if [ -z $1 ]; then
    dynamic_arg=""
  fi

  echo ${dynamic_arg}
  openssl genrsa "${static_arg}" ${dynamic_arg} ...
}
```

Output if `$1` contains whitespaces (e.g. `qw er`):

```
-passout pass:qw er
usage: genrsa [args] [numbits]
...
```

The problem is that when `$1` contains whitespaces and not using quotes for the usage of the ${dynamic_arg}, openssl will interpret my argument as more arguments due to the whitespace.

If I use quotes for the usage of the `dynamic_arg`:

```
openssl genrsa "${static_arg}" "${dynamic_arg}" ...
```

then the error is the same because openssl now interprets my 2 arguments inside the `dynamic_arg` as one (instead of 2).

If I use quotes (both simple or double) inside the `dynamic_arg` initialisation:

```
local dynamic_arg="-passout \"pass:$1\""
```

and not quoting the usage of `dynamic_arg`:

```
openssl genrsa "${static_arg}" ${dynamic_arg} ...
```

it will still complain (displaying usage) for `dynamic_arg` with value:

```
-passout "pass:qw er"
```

How can I make this `dynamic_arg` work and to support white spaces in it?

Answer (score 0):

That's where bash>4 arrays come in hand.

```
function foo() {
  local -a dynamic_arg
  dynamic_arg=("-passout" "pass:$1") # pass:$1 is enclosed in "
  if [ -z $1 ]; then
    dynamic_arg=()
  fi
  echo "${dynamic_arg[@]}"
  openssl genrsa "${static_arg}" "${dynamic_arg[@]}" ...
  # "${arr[@]}" expands into "${arr[0]}" "${arr[1]}" ... properly enclosed in "
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use this solution (updated the question with the constraints). I am using `/bin/sh`